# fullcalendar viewdisplay alternative function

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I want upgrade my full calendar to latest version. all working But some data I am fetching from database using php. some functions are creates problems like view display function. 
Please check below code.

```
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        if (view.name != lastView )
        {
            if (view.name == 'month') 
            {   
                    $('#meetings').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', '/meetings/meetinglistdays/my').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                    $('#meetings').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', '/meetings/meetingslistmonth/my');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#meetings').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', '/meetings/meetinglistdays/my' ); 
                $('#meetings').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', '/meetings/meetingslistmonth/my' ).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                $('#meetings').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', '/meetings/meetinglistdays/my' );
            }
            lastView = view.name;
        }

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem and the reason behind was `Renamed/Removed` functions  and `viewDisplay` option has been deprecated in favor of the `viewRender` callback.

Note: Before moving towards the migration you should try reading the `migration` docs [click here for migration docs](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/) And the solution to your problem exist [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/) at the very bottom in`Renamed/Removed` section.

Comment: Hello Valar. Thanks for your responce. I replaced viewDisplay to viewRender. First level My code                                                                                  viewDisplay: function(view) {  I replaced view render                           viewRender :  function(view) {                                                                       After replacing viewRender I got like this error .  "     Navigated to http://localhost:8091        "

Comment: can you specify the problem a bit more and accept the answer if it helped you it might help someone like you as well.